# PRNG - Algorithm: Performance vs Readability

Tags: performance, design-patterns, actionscript-3

I have a PRNG-Algorithm:

```
/**
* Generates an integer. Min: 0 | Max: total - 1
* @param    total The number of possibilities.
* @return The generated number.*/
public function generate_normal(total:int):int
{
    _seed = (_seed * MULTIPLIER) % MODULUS;
    return (_seed * total / MODULUS);
}
```

The constants are defined as follows:

```
/**The Multiplier.*/
private const MULTIPLIER:int = 48271;

/**The Modulus.*/
private const MODULUS:int = 2147483647;
```

This is readable and understandable, but pretty slow (~50% more time).

Simply using the numbers would be faster, but less readable. Will people call these numbers "magic" and kill me or will everything be fine? Should I change this part in the class description:

```
Modulus suggested 1988 by Stephen K. Park and Keith W. Miller.
Multiplier suggested 1993 by Park and Miller.
```

to this:

```
Modulus (2147483647) suggested 1988 by Stephen K. Park and Keith W. Miller.
Multiplier (48271) suggested 1993 by Park and Miller.
```

*Should I keep my approach or use the numbers directly?*

**TL;DR What's more important, performance or readability?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one answer.

**Performance**

How often is `generate_normal` called? Is it called on a program critical path or only during set up?

Could you cache a bunch of numbers before hand and only replenish the cache when you run out?

**Readability**

How many people will read this code over its lifetime? How often will you have to come back to the code?

**Compromise**

If you notice a substantial penalty using the `private const` construct, then do the following:

```
/**The Multiplier. Suggested 1993 by Park and Miller.*/
private const MULTIPLIER:int = 48271; // folded into code below

/**The Modulus. Suggested 1988 by Stephen K. Park and Keith W. Miller.*/
private const MODULUS:int = 2147483647; // folded into code below

...

public function generate_normal(total:int):int
{
    // Values folded from definitions ...
    // _seed = (_seed * MULTIPLIER) % MODULUS;
    _seed = (_seed * 48271) % 2147483647;
    // return (_seed * total / MODULUS);
    return (_seed * total / 2147483647);
}
```

Comment: Performance: I'll be using it mostly for games, about 5 times per frame; nice idea with the cache. Readability: I think that at least I'll be sharing it with some people who help me with the games.

Answer (score 0):

Readability:

```
>>> hex(2147483647)
'0x7fffffff'
```

Using a hex constant would be *way* more readable.

Performance:

Honestly I can't believe that *using the numbers would be faster*. Do you have any measurements to support the claim?

Comment: I just made a little test: I stored the current time in milliseconds, tested with constants (25.000.000 iterations) and stored the current time minus the time before. Then I did the same again without constants. The times varied alot, but this was one run:   With constants: 3398 | Without constants: 2211 | With constants took 53% more time.

Comment: there's a small increase (7-9%) but i can't see anything close to 53%. maybe there's some complex scope that makes it difficult to go read those values every time